# Generalized Advantage Estimation

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, control-theory

I have three questions regarding the paper [High-Dimensional Continuous Control Using Generalized Advantage Estimation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02438):

1) The authors define $\gamma$-just estimators below. My question is: Does the expectation on the right hand side have to start in $s_0$? It looks like the pair $(s_t,a_t)$ is fixed, so shouldn't the expectation start from $(s_{t},a_{t})$ instead? [image]

2) This question is a direct continuation of question 1. The proof of proposition 1 says: [image]
Does anyone understand the last step of the derivation, where $a_t$ suddenly doesn't play a role anymore, but $s_t$ still does?

2) The Generalized Advantage Estimator is defined as
[image]
Later on, the authors state

> $GAE(\gamma,1)$ is $\gamma$-just regardless of $V$

However, if you plug $1$ in for $\lambda$ in the very first line (the actual definition), isn't the estimator just zero? You can't plug in $1$ into the last line of the derivation, since you would divide by zero in the second to last step...?

Comment: Equations 17 and 18 address special cases of $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = 1$. I  think that Eq. 16 is for the $0 < \lambda < 1$ case. The authors seem to imply that Eq. 16 is a generalized estimator which is distinct from the special cases.

Comment: Yes, it definitely makes sense that the definition in Eq. 16 is only for $\lambda \in (0,1)$. I guess I was just confused by the phrasing ("There are two notable special cases of this formula, obtained by setting $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = 1$") that was used to introduce Eq. 17 and Eq. 18. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't provide a more comprehensive reply. I only glanced at the paper and am not overwhelmingly familiar with RL topics.

Comment: For the 1st question, the discounted advantage $A$ will take care of $a_t$ by the definition.

Comment: And [this document](https://ewrl.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/ewrl12_2015_submission_18.pdf) elaborates more on GAE proof